# Python pandas Datetime vs Timestamp import problems

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I'm having a very weird error when importing in two excel files.  The format in the first column is the same (excel has it as custom 'm/d/yy h:mm' for both).  I'm importing them both using

```
df = pd.read_excel(df_file, sheet.name, header=0, skiprows=[1],\
parse_cols= [0,5,6], infer_datetime_format=True, index_col=0, na_values=['NAN'])
```

The weird thing is that one gives df.index output as:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-04-26 00:00:00, ..., 2014-12-21 11:50:00]
Length: 65532, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Whereas the other (say df2) is giving the output as a list of datetime.datetime objects instead of a DatetimeIndex.  I tried using pd.Timestamp(df2.index) which told me to use df2.to_timestamp(), but then it says that Index has no attribute to_timestamp().  What are some common reasons why this could be happening?  I can give files or more examples if needed.  I'm hoping this is just something trivial that I'm missing.  Thanks!

As requested - Here are some things that might help in figured out the problem.  The output of df2.index is (truncated)

```
Out[62]:
Index([2014-04-26 00:00:00, 2014-04-26 00:05:00, 2014-04-26 00:10:00, 
2014-04-26 00:15:00, 2014-04-26 00:20:00, ...... 2014-04-26 07:50:00, 
2014-04-26 07:55:00, 2014-04-26 08:00:00, 2014-04-26 08:05:00, 
2014-04-26 08:10:00, 2014-04-26 08:15:00, ...], dtype='object')
```

type(df2.index[0]) is:

```
datetime.datetime
```

df2.index.to_datetime() gives:

```
ValueError: Unable to convert [datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 26, 0, 0) 
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 26, 0, 5)
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 26, 0, 10) ...,
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 20, 40)
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 20, 45)
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 20, 50)] to datetime dtype
```

If you still need the excel files I can host them somewhere, where is a good place to do so with files that are around ~16 MB?

I think the real question I'm having here is why read_excel isn't parsing the dates into a DatetimeIndex and instead an Index of datetime objects.  Still trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the excel files that cause problems.

Comment: Did you try `pd.to_datetime(d2.index)` ?

Comment: Further, please show the output of `df2` and `df2.index` (what you say returns a list of datetimes)